# how to select join in laravel with condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
 public function clientcmd()
    {
        $client = Commande::join('clients', 'commande.id_cli', "=", 'clients.id')
        ->select('clients.*')
        ->where('commande.id_cli', '')
        ->get();
        return response()->json($client);
    }
```

I want to select all the client where id client = id cli in command table but that not work they return an empty array

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the data in your table. I assume you want to select fields whose `id_cli` field is not empty string.

```
$client = Commande::join('clients', 'commande.id_cli', "=", 'clients.id')
        ->select('clients.*')
        ->where('commande.id_cli','!=', '')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Query builder`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 
$clients = DB::table('clients')
            ->join('commande', 'commande.id_cli', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->select('clients.*')
            ->where(//you can put condition here)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Client Model to get all client records

```
$clients = Client::select('*')
            ->join('commande', 'commande.id_cli', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->where("clients.id",$client_id) // put your condition here
            ->get();
```